# app uses cloud computing?

Tags: iphone, cloud, system, distributed

There is iPhone app provides database to save your personal info also your location .you can share your location with your friend.
how could I know if this app uses cloud computing or not?
also can I say that app is example for distributed system ?
thank you and sorry for my poor English .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it sends messages to other computers over an asynchronous network, its a distributed system. So yes, anything that sends data over the internet is a distributed system.

Cloud computing is a buzzword that is hard to define. You could look at the IP that the app is talking to, and lookup if that IP is registered by Amazon EC2, Google compute engine, Microsoft Azure or some other big provider; in which case, they are using "cloud computers". Otherwise, it's hard to tell.